# Columns not staking in smaller screens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using a simple layout in **bootstrap** but cannot make the page fully responsive. The columns are not stacking when I reduce the browser width.

I already tried the SO suggestions below but none helped:

- include the link to `bootstrap.min.css` on head
- include `content="width=device-width` on head

You can check an online version of my problem [here](http://optimize.nmob.pt/Na%20Imprensa.html). You can see that the columns are not stacking.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have other CSS rules that are overriding the bootstrap ones

Comment: As the comment above mentioned there are css rules overwriting the bootstrap styles. Remove ```.articles-area .row```styling and it should work

Comment: I think you might have a min-width issue. Also, it doesn't make sense for it to stack. Consider the case when your device width is 50 px. What would you like to happen? Should the site be an endless stack of divs piled up one against the other? That would make for a very ugly site. Consider re-designing your site to match the real-estate you have on the screen. In the case of mobiles, perhaps it's better to show a couple of icons rather than an endless array of text paragraphs.

Comment: How did you spell stacking wrong on STACKOVERFLOW :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following lines in your CSS override the normal widths of bootstrap. Remove or adjust following lines if you don't want fixed sizes for all columns.

```
.articles-area .row [class*="col-"]{
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 33%;
}
```